# Group a date range by month in aggregation mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider the following example, a series of documents in MongoDB:

```js
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("608142d41165f010faf11781"),
        "title" : "Event 1",
        "startDate" : ISODate("2020-11-25T21:00:00.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2020-11-27T21:00:00.000Z")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("608142df1165f010faf11782"),
        "title" : "Event 2",
        "startDate" : ISODate("2020-11-28T21:00:00.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2020-12-03T21:00:00.000Z")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("608142e61165f010faf11783"),
        "title" : "Event 3",
        "startDate" : ISODate("2020-12-14T21:00:00.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2020-17-28T21:00:00.000Z")
    }
]
```

There are events that start with a month and end with the same month.

**startDate: 2020-11-25**

**endDate: 2020-11-27**

On the other hand, there are events that begin with one month and end with another. eg:

**startDate: 2020-11-28**

**endDate: 2020-12-03**

The result I am looking for is to group events by month and year. if the event starts with one month and ends with another, **it will be grouped into the start month and also into the end month.**

After grouping, I need to get a result set that looks like this:

```js
{
    "_id": {
        "month": 11,
        "year": 2020
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "Event 1"
        },
        {
            "title": "Event 2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": {
        "month": 12,
        "year": 2020
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "Event 2"
        },
        {
            "title": "Event 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `$project` to show required fields, make array of both `startDate` and `endDate`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `date` array
- `$group` by month and year and construct array of unique `title`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      title: 1,
      date: ["$startDate", "$endDate"]
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$date" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        month: { $month: "$date" },
        year: { $year: "$date" }
      },
      events: { $addToSet: { title: "$title" } }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5xGdz6_vY3w)